# My vs You on site pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, wording

Just noticed on moderator election pages:

- When I’ve voted:

> [image]

- When I’ve not voted:

> [image]

It seems there’s some kind of inconsistency. Should we use “I” in the latter case, or use “Your” in the first one?

Yet another issue is using bold font style vs regular for phrases.

Answer (score 12):

We actually just defined how we feel about this in our [content guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#pronouns). We might be able to get this into our next bug duty rotation.

Comment: (*"oxford comma"* → *"[Oxford comma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Oxford_comma#Noun)"* on that page.)

Comment: Pull requests welcome 

Answer (score 3):

This has been addressed now and should show up in the next elections

Comment: What’s about different font styles? Bold vs regular.